# __attribute__((always_inline)) failing

Tags: c, gcc

I wonder if some one can shed some light on this. I got a header file with a few `always_inline` methods, which gets included several places. Since I upgraded the OS (Debian Wheezy) with a newer version of gcc 4.7.1 I am getting a load of warnings on failing inlines. I am able to compile this successfully on gcc 4.4.5 (Debian Squeezy). Compile command I am using is

```
gcc -g -Wall -O0 -o [prog_name] [sources].c -l[link libraries]
```

Code:

```
#ifndef __MCIDSHEADER_H__
#define __MCIDSHEADER_H__

#include <stdlib.h>

/* C functions */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    /* Constructor and destructor */
    mcidsheader* mcidsheader_new(mcidsheader* obj, sqlite3* ids, crSettings* settings);
    void mcidsheader_delete(mcidsheader* obj);

/* set schedule number */
__attribute__ ((always_inline)) static int mcidsheader_set_schedno(mcidsheader* obj, unsigned int var)
{
    MC_CHK_OBJ(obj);
    obj->var_sched_no = var;
    /* memset schedule number */
    memset(obj->var_sched, 0, MCIDSHEADER_SCHEDNUM_SZ);
    /* copy to local */
    sprintf(obj->var_sched, "%i", var);
    obj->var_flg = 0;
    return 0;
}

/* Get schedule number */
__attribute__ ((always_inline)) static const char* mcidsheader_get_schedno(const mcidsheader* obj)
{
    MC_CHK_OBJ_PTR(obj);
    return obj->var_sched;
}

/* set job number */
__attribute__ ((always_inline)) static int mcidsheader_set_jobnumber(mcidsheader* obj, const char* var)
{
    MC_CHK_OBJ(obj);

    /* memset buff */
    memset(obj->var_jobnumber, 0, MCIDSHEADER_JOBNUMBER_SZ);
    MC_CHK_OBJ(var);
    /* copy to local */
    strcpy(obj->var_jobnumber, var);
    obj->var_flg = 0;
    return 0;
}

/* get job number */
__attribute__ ((always_inline)) static const char* mcidsheader_get_jobnumber(const mcidsheader* obj)
{
    MC_CHK_OBJ_PTR(obj);
    return obj->var_jobnumber;
}

/* set project */
__attribute__ ((always_inline)) static int mcidsheader_set_project(mcidsheader* obj, const char* var)
{
    MC_CHK_OBJ(obj);

    /* memset buff */
    memset(obj->var_project, 0, MCIDSHEADER_PROJECT_SZ);
    MC_CHK_OBJ(var);

    /* copy to local */
    strcpy(obj->var_project, var);
    obj->var_flg = 0;
    return 0;
}

/* Get project name */
__attribute__ ((always_inline)) static const char* mcidsheader_get_project(const mcidsheader* obj)
{
    MC_CHK_OBJ_PTR(obj);
    return obj->var_project;
}

/* Set client */
__attribute__ ((always_inline)) static int  mcidsheader_set_client(mcidsheader* obj, const char* var)
{
    MC_CHK_OBJ(obj);

    /* memset buff */
    memset(obj->var_client, 0, MCIDSHEADER_CLIENT_SZ);
    MC_CHK_OBJ(var);

    /* copy to local */
    strcpy(obj->var_client, var);
    obj->var_flg = 0;
    return 0;
}

/* get client */
__attribute__ ((always_inline)) static const char* mcidsheader_get_client(const mcidsheader* obj)
{
    MC_CHK_OBJ(obj);
    return obj->var_client;
}

/* set date */
__attribute__ ((always_inline)) static int mcidsheader_set_date(mcidsheader* obj, const char* var)
{
    MC_CHK_OBJ(obj);
    /* memset buff */
    memset(obj->var_date, 0, MCIDSHEADER_DATE_SZ);
    MC_CHK_OBJ(var);
    /* copy to local */
    strcpy(obj->var_date, var);
    obj->var_flg = 0;
    return 0;
}

/* get date */
__attribute__ ((always_inline)) static const char* mcidsheader_get_date(const mcidsheader* obj)
{
    MC_CHK_OBJ_PTR(obj);
    return obj->var_date;
}

/* Get struct size */
__attribute__ ((always_inline)) static unsigned int mcidsheader_get_size(const mcidsheader* obj)
{
    if(!obj) return 0;
    return obj->var_size;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* __MCIDSHEADER_H__ */
```

Comment: And what do the warnings say exactly?  It sounds probably that it just can't inline those functions for whatever reason.

Comment: @Goz that's what GCC always throw when you do always_inline attribute...  and to workaround this add an `inline` before the attribute.

Comment: @anojmperera I'll add an answer, please accept it.  So it would be easier to find.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html):

> GCC does not inline any functions when not optimizing unless you specify the `always_inline` attribute for the function, like this:
>
> ```
> /* Prototype.  */
> inline void foo (const char) __attribute__((always_inline));
> ```

So, to workaround this issue, you have to add an `inline` before the attribute.

Comment: @DietrichEpp why even bother posting such useless comment?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, answers are expected to be relatively complete.  See [How To Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).  Ideally, someone who comes to this page from Google should be able to understand the solution by reading the answer, without having to hunt for comments or follow links.

Comment: My earlier comment was a bit rude, sorry for that.

Comment: And that was exactly my point, make an answer for googlers, but thank you for the link, i'll read it and possibly improve my answer.

Comment: Adding the `inline` doesn't fix it.  You also have to add `static`, which the OP already had in his code.

Comment: Well, OP is lazy and that's bad. However user9000, the always_inline docs you cited are actually *wrong*. I had this recently changed to:

>Generally, functions are not inlined unless optimization is specified. For functions declared inline, this attribute inlines the function independent of any restrictions that otherwise apply to inlining. Failure to inline such a function is diagnosed as an error. Note that if such a function is called indirectly the compiler may or may not inline it depending on optimization level and a failure to inline an indirect call may or may not be diagnosed.

Comment: @DanielSantos I am pretty sure it was as-is when I copied it from GCC's documentation